# What does vagrant-aws provide and how to use it in production version?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, vagrant

I have used `Vagrant` with default `Virtualbox` provider. It uses `Virtualbox` to simulate a OS, such as `Ubuntu 14.04` on **my local computer**.

`Vagrant` has `AWS` provider as well. I have read [the Official document](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws), but I am confused about the following things:

1. Where does this provider runs on, my `local computer` or the `AWS` instance?

   - If it runs on my local computer and only simulates the `AWS` instance, why does the `SSH key` need to be set?
   - If it runs on the `AWS` instance, will the intended `AMI`, such as `Ubuntu 14.04`, being setup `directly` on the instance or through `simulating tools` used by `AWS` to `simulate` a OS on the instance, like what `Virtual box` does based on the local computer?
2. As `Vagrant` adds in overhead on the system by using `Simulating Provider`, whether is it a good idea to use `Vagrant` in production version? If not, how to put the `Vagrant box` into the `production server`, such as the `AWS` instance?

Comment: The AWS provider manages intances on AWS, not on your local machine.

Comment: There is no overhead on the managed instance, like `Virtualbox` adds overhead on the hosted OS, isn't it?